# Remove all inputs with similar names

Tags: jquery

I am using this to remove a specific `input` button I don't want to be shown.

```
$('input[name="FRANCHISE_SOUND0001"]').remove();
```

But I'd like to remove all of these inputs.
There is 100's of them and each have a unique identifier depending on the logged in user.

```
input[name="FRANCHISE_SOUND_FILE0001"]
input[name="FRANCHISE_SOUND_FILE0002"]
input[name="FRANCHISE_SOUND_FILE0003"]
input[name="FRANCHISE_SOUND_FILE0004"]
```

The only constant is `input[name="FRANCHISE_SOUND_FILE"]` where the 4 last digits following FILE is unique to the user.

How can I remove them all at once?

Can this be done in same manner as above

```
$('#NOTES0001').remove();
$('#NOTES0002').remove();
$('#NOTES0341').remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS selector comparison operator `^=` which means "begining with" like so:

```
$('input[name^="FRANCHISE_SOUND_FILE"]').remove();
```

For `id`:

```
$('[id^="NOTES"]').remove();
```

For `class`:

```
$('[class^="Some_className_first_characters"]').remove();
```

It works the same for any HTML attribute.
W3C easy tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp).

You may be interested by "contains" `*=` operator too! Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp).

;)

Comment: think you very much , simple to do and i like that

Comment: how would something similar work for this  $('#NOTES0001').remove();  , $('#NOTES0002').remove();  , $('#NOTES0341').remove();

Comment: `$('[id^="NOTES"]').remove();` ;)